# Is there a Snipping tool for WIndows XP

Tags: windows-xp, snapshot

Is there a tool available for Windows XP which is similar to the [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) for Windows 7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the free [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) screen capture utility.  After installing it, you just use the print screen button as normal but now it comes up with a selection tool instead of screen snapshotting the entire screen.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following information on Microsofts website [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/ce13fd12-d096-4caa-9073-e0f70696a840/). Typos and all! XD

> Sinpping tool is included in Experience Pack which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=33790048-269B-4838-AB9E-74B64626A494&displaylang=en#Overview).
>
> Microsoft Experience Pack for Tablet
>   PC can work with Windows XP. However,
>   please pay attention that there are
>   some sepecial reqestments for Windows
>   XP as below:
>
> - Windows XP Service Pack 2
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1
> - Windows Media Player 10 (required for Media Transfer)
> - At least 50 MB of available free space on your hard disk

Comment: +1.  This is a better answer to the question if only because it IS the Snipping Tool, haha.

Comment: The installer will not run, insisting that Tablet PC Edition is required.

Comment: @SamBrightman: are you doing this on Windows XP? That is the ONLY operating system that this question applies to. Also, I was simply identifying how to use Snipping Tool on Windows XP, which is exactly what the questioner wanted. I would highly suggest Greenshot and I use it daily at work. Try Greenshot like the other answer insists.

Comment: Yes David, it does not work on Windows XP using the current version. I have also found Greenshot quite nice.

Comment: Unfortunately that "experience pack" download seems to only be for windows tablets running XP, or something like that, not desktops.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to mention the possible option of simply using what is built into Windows XP.  Press Print Screen to capture a whole screen, or hold Alt-Printscreen to capture just a current window.  Either way, paste the resulting graphic into a program such as MS Paint, which can be used to make further edits.

However, for those who wish alternative options, I found quite a few from the goldmine of a thread that David provided.  That thread is at [Microsoft Social Media site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ce13fd12-d096-4caa-9073-e0f70696a840/snipping-tool-for-windows-xp-not-tablet-pc-or-vista?forum=winservergenf8ce2f79-798f-4134-b1e3-d6c9c7d0c4b5).  However, the thread also contained a number of other details to make things work, and also referred to several other options.  Since there were some later modifications to earlier instructions, I simplified the situation by compiling the details here for convenience.

(Note that I don't have a system running XP handy, so, for now, this is all based on hearsay.  I'm presuming that people interested in this answer may be able to test this.)

- Use official code by Microsoft

  - Obtain the Microsoft Office XP Pack for Tablet PC (Tablet Pack).  (This appears to be the correct name for the software, and is the same software mentioned in David's answer in this Stack Exchange question.  His answer appears to be based on Morgan Che's answer from the Microsoft site.)

    - [Download page for Microsoft Office XP Pack for Tablet PC (Tablet Pack)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=33790048-269B-4838-AB9E-74B64626A494&displaylang=en#Overview)
  - If you have Windows XP for Tablet PC (technically a different OS than Windows XP), then installation should be straightforward.
  - If you want to try to use this with regular Windows XP, that may be an option, but will involve third party software, and more work.

    - Possible alternative (if this is suitable trustable by you...  This is not necessarily recommended by me...)  [Third party download for Snipping Tool and the Dev Kit 1.7](http://mir.cr/SSUBSUYP) posted by "cexeh" on the Microsoft Thread.  Whether this is more trustworthy, or less trustworthy, than any of the other software (like isxunpack, perhaps) is a detail I'm not trying to determine for you.  Download at your own risk.
    - I suggest starting with the requirements mentioned by Morgan Che: XP SP2, .NET Framework 1.1, Media Player 10, 50MB of disk space

      - dapatoumba's answer provides instructions, and says, "Note that the tool will not run on nLited Windows installs without IE/WMP".  So if you used "nLite" to install Windows without that common functionality, then this may not work.
    - Obtain additional required software

      - i6comp ([i6cmop02.zip](https://www.sac.sk/download/pack/i6comp02.zip)) (TOOGAM's note: The ftp.sac.sk, used by this hyperlink, is recognized as generally being trustable)
      - isxunpack ([isxunpack download](http://www.legroom.net/scripts/download.php?file=uniextract161_noinst))
    - Additional software that might be helpful

      - dapatoumba's answer, on the Microsoft thread, also said to install WinRAR.  However, there isn't any clear reason why...  I suppose this is to Extract Launcher.msi from Microsoft's OPSetup.exe (step 3 of NSKSAM's instructions in the original thread)
      - [Microsoft Windows XP Tablet PC Edition Software Development Kit 1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b46d4b83-a821-40bc-aa85-c9ee3d6e9699&displaylang=en) may be helpful if the program complains about "`The DDE server did not acknowledge the command, within the time allowed. Application=, Topic=`".  (That error was reported by somebody who mentioned this Dev kit as a solution.  That person was using XP Pro Service Pack 3.)
    - Extract Launcher.msi

      - Apparently this is what WinRar is helpful for

        - Unrar did not recognize the OPSetup.exe as a valid file.  7-zip could extract from the required file, but did not seem to make a file called Launcher.msi
      - To do this, use Explorer.  Right-click on the OPSetup.exe file.  And choose "`Extract to InstallExperiencePack\`".
    - Install the software by running this command: "msiexec /a Launcher.msi"
    - After installing, rename `Microsoft\Experience Pack\Data\Sniptool.dat` to `SnipTool.exe`
    - Use: `isxunpack.exe SnipTool.exe`
    - Copy the i6comp.exe (downloaded earlier) to the resuliting Disk1 sub-directory
    - From that directory, run: "`i6comp.exe e data1.cab`"
    - Ignore error messages, and enjoy SnippingTool.exe
- Or, use some other options, such as one of these:

  - [windows xp snipping tool](http://xpsnipping.codeplex.com) third party application, with source code available, by StratMan123 (who posted to the Microsoft thread)
  - [Snippy](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Snippy/) (mentioned by Ruth, Brunette-31, on the Microsoft thread, who noted this is "not as fancy or as nice")
  - MWSnap v3 (recommended by S. Buchanan, Sawdustpsycho, on the Microsoft thread.  No hyperlink was provided.)
  - [HP Smart Web Printing](http://www.hp.com/global/us/en/consumer/digital_photography/free/software/smart-web-printing.html)

That is completing the roundup of information from the Microsoft thread.  Note that there may be other options, too, like "Greenshot" which is mentioned in another answer here.

Comment: excellent omnibus answer! Thanks for your time! ( Can't believe this hasn't received any other votes! :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I developed a while back, it works just like Snipping Tool in Windows 7:

http://glassocean.net/snip-tool-a-free-snipping-tool-compatible-with-windows-xp/